# Preventing XSS attack Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, ckeditor, xss

Currently I am using a CKEditor text editor. It escape's html but I want to prevent it from server side.
What is the best way to prevent XSS When we are using Text Editor in Python/Django?

Answer (score 0):

Automatically or explicitly [escape your output in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/), e.g.

```
{% autoescape on %}
    {{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

or

```
{{ body|escape }}
```

If you want to only escape JavaScript the "right" way to do it would be to convert the HTML to DOM, walk the tree of nodes, and remove any script elements.  A less elegant and imperfect solution would be to use a regular expression to replace any script tags.

Comment: thanks, I want to remove all harmful tags and attributes like I need <a> tag but some one can write js in href attribute. I need <img> tag but some one can write js in src and so on. and all events also takes js. So what do you say?

Comment: Yeah that's a tough problem. Take a look at this JS solution: https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer and also this other SO question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976053/xss-which-html-tags-and-attributes-can-trigger-javascript-events