# 'nxml-mode' validation error with 'usemap' attribute

Tags: xml, validation, emacs, xhtml, relaxng

In my **XHTML** documents, **nxml-mode** (via its included XHTML [Relax NG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG) compact schema) is flagging the values of the `usemap` attributes with the error `Attribute value invalid`.

```html
<img src="sample_image.png"
     usemap="#sample_image_map"
     alt="Sample Image"
     border="0" />
```

The problem appears to be the presence of the leading `#` character in the value of the `usemap` attribute. If I remove the `#` character, **nxml-mode** indicates the value is valid. But the leading `#` character is generally expected in the value of `usemap` which is commonly used to reference a `map` definition elsewhere in the file.

Is **nxml-mode** falsely raising a validation error on the value of `usemap`?

*(Note that I am using **Emacs 24.2.1** and the version of **nxml-mode** that it includes.)*

---

Here is a full XHTML example which validates at [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>nxml-mode Validation Problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--  The '#' is OK here. -->
    <a href="#sample_link">Sample Link</a>

    <map id="sample_image_map">
      <area shape="poly" coords="100,0, 200,0, 200,50, 100,50"
            alt="Sample Area"/>
    </map>

    <!--
        * For the value of the 'usemap' attribute, 'nxml-mode'
        * issues the error 'Attribute value invalid'.
        *
        * However, if the '#' is removed from the value
        * '#sample_image_map', 'nxml-mode' indicates the value
        * is valid.
    -->
    <img src="sample_image.png"
         usemap="#sample_image_map"
         alt="Sample Image"
         border="0" />

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Here is the result of my research...other answers of course welcome.]*

It appears to me that **nxml-mode** may be improperly mapping the `usemap` attribute to `IDREF`. Here is the definition for `usemap` in ***etc/schemas/xhtml-csismap.rnc*** (a [Relax NG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG) compact schema file):

```
usemap.attlist = attribute usemap { IDREF.datatype }?
```

When I change the definition to instead map `usemap` to `URI`, **nxml-mode** is happy:

```
usemap.attlist = attribute usemap { URI.datatype }?
```

**Now, is this a legitimate change?**

According to Wikipedia, [XHTML derives from HTML 4.01](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#Versions_of_XHTML). I cannot find any specific guidance for `usemap` in the [XHTML 1.0 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/). However, [the HTML 4.01 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.6) does indeed indicate that the `usemap` attribute is a URI:

> usemap = *[uri](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-uri)* [[CT](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#see-type-for-case)]

Furthermore, the [HTML 4.01 documentation for the `IMG` tag](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/img.html) at HTMLHelp.com says:

> The **USEMAP** attribute is used with client-side image maps to give the
>   location of the map definition. While this value may be a **full**
>   **URI**--allowing a single map definition to be applied to multiple
>   pages--many browsers will only find map definitions in the same file,
>   effectively limiting the **USEMAP** value to a fragment identifier such as
>   **"#map"**.

**Finally,** note the inclusion of `<img usemap=url>` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725168/1497596) to the question [COMPLETE list of HTML tag attributes which have a URL value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2725156/1497596).