# HTML attributes that can contain javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a simple list of all the html attributes that can contain javascript that will automatically run when an action is performed. I know this will differ between browsers and versions but I'd rather be safer than sorry. I currently know of the following javascript attributes: `onload`, `onclick`, `onchange`, `onmouseover`, `onmouseout`, `onmousedown`, and `onmouseup`

**Backstory:**
I'm getting a full html document from an untrusted source and I want to strip all javascript that could run from the original html document so I'm removing all script tags as well as any attributes that could hold javascript before its displayed in an iframe. For this implantation there is no server side processing and no way of sandboxing the code since I need to run javascript that is being added locally after all of the original javascript is removed.

Comment: Found some useful info and checks at https://html5sec.org/

Comment: You probably should just use a thoroughly tested HTML sanitizer library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two places where Javascript can be used in HTML attributes:

1. Any `onEVENT` attribute. I suggest just treating any attribute that begins with `on` as an event binding, and strip them all out.
2. Any attribute that can contain a URI will be executed as Javascript if the URI uses the `javascript:` scheme, such as `href` and `src`. A complete list is in

[COMPLETE list of HTML tag attributes which have a URL value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725156/complete-list-of-html-tag-attributes-which-have-a-url-value)

Comment: I hadn't though about validating the URI attributes, do you know any good way of doing it in Javascript?

Comment: Just check whether the value of the attribute begins with `javascript:`.

Comment: Thanks, think I'm still missing some attack vectors in css but its a good start.

Comment: I think the only place it could appear in CSS would be styles that allow `url(...)` values. So look for `url(javascript:...)`.

Comment: Its a bit more complicated https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.234_-_CSS_Escape_And_Strictly_Validate_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Style_Property_Values But my main problem is how to validate external css files.

Comment: My understanding is that CSS can't execute JS in standards conformant browsers.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: @DylanYoung See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css

Comment: That doesn't answer the question :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3

Scroll down to 18.2.3 Intrinsic events

I've had a similar requirement in a project.  Don't forget to strip script elements, as well.

Comment: That doesn't include `href="javascript:..."` and `src="javascript:..."`

Comment: I though there should be a simple list somewhere but I couldn't find it. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Use this as well: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/webappapis.html#dom-globaleventhandlers-onabort.  Otherwise you're going to miss a lot global event handlers.