# All possible html tags that can have "src" attribute

Tags: html

I want to know all the possible tags in html where "src" is a valid attribute to use. Ex: img, source, iframe, etc. 
Where can I get the complete list of html tags that can have "src" attribute ?

Comment: you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725156/complete-list-of-html-tag-attributes-which-have-a-url-value Hope this will be helpfull for you

Comment: Please check below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725156/complete-list-of-html-tag-attributes-which-have-a-url-value