# Java regex to enable link inside text except already enclosed tag

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing, html-parsing

Suppose a **user input** text that contains HTML and maybe links , I want to enable links , and make already_tag_closed urls intact .

(I know there are a lot of regex url pattern questions asked , but I cannot find this solution)

for example :

```
String urlRegex = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

String s = ...
urlPattern.matcher(s).replaceAll("<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>")
```

It can translate `"google https://google.com"` to `google <a href='https://google.com' target='_blank'>https://google.com</a>`  , good.

But if string is

```
"<a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">google</a> " +
" http://www.google.com/  " +
" <a href=\"https://facebook.com/\">facebook</a> " +
" https://facebook.com ";
```

It will become

```
<a href="<a href='http://www.google.com/' target='_blank'>http://www.google.com/</a>">google</a>  <a href='http://www.google.com/' target='_blank'>http://www.google.com/</a>   <a href="<a href='https://facebook.to/' target='_blank'>https://facebook.to/</a>">facebook</a>  <a href='https://facebook.com' target='_blank'>https://facebook.com</a>
```

It should not touch values in `href` , so I change the `urlRegex` to :

```
urlRegexExceptAnchor = "(?<!\\<a\\ href=\")(http|https):\\/\\/[^ ]*";
```

Well , it can handle text mixed with anchor tags.

**But** , if the text includes `iframe` , it will fail again :

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnytimes%2Fposts%2F10151112309519999&width=500" width="500" height="525" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

becomes

```
<iframe src="<a href='https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnytimes%2Fposts%2F10151112309519999&width=500"' target='_blank'>https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnytimes%2Fposts%2F10151112309519999&width=500"</a> width="500" height="525" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

It's invalid again.

I think I'll face more and more situation , because [There are a lot of tags that accepts URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725168/298430) . I cannot just escape `a` or `iframe` tags...

The text is input by user , sure I can filter out some invalid tags , such as `form` , `head` , `input` ... , but there are still a lot of tags to process... ( or even inlined css background url )

What I can think of now is to use something like `JSoup` to transfer the whole text to html doc , and process the textNode one by one. But I think that's too overkill. (Each page display will invoke `JSoup`  ... )

Is there any easier ways to achieve this ?

Comment: Do not use regex to parse/process an HTML file. Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: It isn't overkill, it's the way to go. If each displayed page invokes your script, change your app design. This must be done once and for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone facing similar problems , this is my `JSoup` solution :

```
  private static void processNode(Node node) {
    if (node instanceof TextNode) {

      Node parent = node.parent();
      if (parent != null && (StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(parent.nodeName(),
        "a", "iframe", "embed" , "img" , "object" , "script" , "video" , "applet"))) {
        logger.debug("parent = {} , skipped", parent.nodeName());
      }
      else {
        TextNode textNode = (TextNode) node;

        String text = textNode.text();
        text = urlPattern.matcher(text).replaceAll("<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>");

        TextNode r = new TextNode(text , null);
        node.replaceWith(r);
      }
    } else if (node instanceof Element) {
      Element ele = (Element) node;
      for (Node childNode : ele.childNodes()) {
        processNode(childNode);
      }
    }
  }
```

It works fine ... (for now)