# Simplify and improve URL matching regex in HTML attributes' values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, url, attributes

First of all, this is not a duplicate of any of the various questions about URL matching regexes here on StackOverflow, since it deals with a specific case (looking in attributes' values), and it's not so much about what the URL text *contains*, but rather about its *delimiters* in HTML attributes' values (could also be about its typical *position* in attributes' values, e.g. it's always the first space separated part of a comma+space delimited subgroup in a, say, `srcset` attribute value).

Now to the actual problem... I have this carefully constructed array of possible URL containing attribute values ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725168) helped me in building the test case scenario below - basically you can have either single or multiple URLs that are separated by spaces or comma+spaces, but following a clear order withing string subgroups in the latter case):

```
var avs = 
[
'http://www.hq.com/pics/favicons/favicon.ico',
'/pics/favicons/favicon.ico',
'pics/favicons/favicon.ico',
'http://c.abc.net/11p306',
'http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar',
'hires.jpg 2x, superhires.jpg a/ # a# #a 1.2x, a.22x 1.2x',
'face-1.jpeg  1x',
'face-1.jpeg 600w',
'face-1.jpeg 600w 200h 1x',
'face-1.jpeg 600w 200h 1x,face-2.jpeg 600w 200h 2x,  face.png 200w 200h',
'face-1.jpeg 600w 200h 1x,  face-2.jpeg 600w  200h 2x,face.png  200w 200h',
' face-1.jpeg 600w 1x, ,, face-2.jpeg 200h 2x,  face.png 200w,http://c.abc.net/11p306 200w',
'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==',
'hires.jpg,superhires.jpg, http://c.abc.net/11p306',
'http://www.hq.com/pics/favicons/favicon.ico,/pics/favicons/favicon.ico',
'hires.jpg superhires.jpg  http://c.abc.net/11p306',
'3;url=hires.jpg',
'url(" img_tree.gif"),,, url(img_flwr.gif),url( img_tree.gif),url(http://c.abc.net/11p306)',
'url("img_tree.gif")',
'url(img_tree.gif )',
'url(  img_tree.gif " )',
'a.c',
'a.c'
];
```

I'm looking to match the URL look-alike (aka those containing `/`, `.`, `?` or `#` - again, it's not about what the URL contains, those are characters you'd normally expect to find in a URL) parts there with a Javascript `match` function, without involving additional steps that pass strings or arrays multiple times - for the sake of execution time, since I could check hundreds of values in an actual HTML. For example, `a.22x` would be a match, but not typical width, height or pixel descriptors that you can find in `srcset` values, e.g. `600w` or `1.2x`.

For example, this code does it to perfection, but it passes things multiple times, and its execution takes twice as long as a single `match`:

```
var res = [];

function extracturls(fv)
  {
  if (fv) {return fv.match(/[^\s\("'=,]*(?:\/|\.|\?|#)[^'"\)\s]*/gi)
                    .map(function(e){return e.replace(/,$/,"");})
                    .filter(function(e){return (!/^\d*\.\d+x$/.test(e));});}
  else {return "";}
  }

t0 = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < avs.length; i++)
  {
  res.push(extracturls(avs[i]));
  }
t1 = performance.now();
console.log(res);
console.log("Execution time: " + (t1 - t0) + " ms.");
```

On the other hand, my preferred `{return fv.match(/[^\s\("'=,]*(?:\/|\.(?!\d+x(?:\s|,\s|$))|\?|#)[^'"\)\s]*?(?='|"|\)|\s|,\s|$)/gi)}` does the trick in half the time, but it also misses `a.22x` (since JS doesn't have a lookbehind to check that the part before the `.` is not one or more digits), plus I have the feeling that I can simplify it or reduce the regex's redundancy (for example, it checks twice for `"` or `)` after the `.`). Can this be done better?

*Note: The valid URLs separated by a simple `,` (with no space following it) in some of the samples above is intentional, as you can have `,` in a URL (you can have quotes or parentheses in the URL as well, but this doesn't go well with the possible quotes or parentheses in the values of the attributes, so I chose not to bother with that). For the attributes' values, I'm assuming common sense comma+space separation of the string parts in the HTML, otherwise the task is nearly impossible, given that almost anything can be a valid URL. In other words, it doesn't have to be perfect, I can live with the regex missing (or including) some super-marginal URL cases that you'll hardly encounter in a HTML.*

EDIT: To sumarize and make it clearer, for the:

- delimiter approach, an URL in an attribute's value (I'm talking about the attributes I'm checking, but I think it can be extended to the majority of them, if not all) is always:

  - preceded by either `^` (start of string),  (space), `,` (comma+space), `;url=`, `url("`, `url('` or `url(`
  - succeeded by either `$` (end of string),  (space), `,` (comma+space), `")`, `')` or `)`
- order-based approach, an URL in an attribute's value is always the first  (space) delimited part of a `,` (comma+space) delimited subgroup, or the whole string if it's a single URL (e.g. if there are no spaces or comma+spaces in the string)

Comment: Are you sure this is doable using only regex?

Comment: If I would look for perfection, it wouldn't be - there are plenty of regexes attempting to identify all the URLs and they all fail. But looking for _realistic URLs_, and take the _delimiters_ (or the _order_ in string) approach as opposed to checking the contents of the candidates surely helps to make it achievable.

Answer (score 0):

After various attempts I settled for something like:

```
function extracturls(fv)
  {
  if (fv) {return fv.match(/[^=\s\("']*(?:\/|\.|\?|#)[^'"\)\s]*?(?='|"|\)|\s|,\s|$)/gi)
                    .filter(function(e){return (!/^\d*\.\d+x$/.test(e));});}
  else {return "";}
  }
```

I won't accept my own answer (at least not yet), because it still passes the string more than once. That being said, it's an improvement over my previous attempts, since the execution time is only 1.5 times the execution for a single pass, compared to a 2.0 factor when it involved mapping (as in the code from my question).