# javascript parser in java

Tags: java, html-parsing

I have a text box which can take any text including html and html embeded with javascript.

I need to validate this data through server side REST API which is implemented in java. Basically I need to do this validation for avoiding XSS vulnerability by not allowing any javascript data to get saved in my database.

When I will receive text from the above mentioned text box on server side API , it should throw error if html text embedded with java script is there but normal html text should be ok.

Example : In the above text box ,data as `<svg onload=alert(document.cookie)/>` should not be allowed  but normal html text like 
`<html><h1>this is test</h1></html>` is allowed.

I tried using JSoup which is a HTML parsing library but I just need to verify if javascript is present in that text instead of checking for html tags.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Please do not tag languages which do not directly involve your question. Right now members who know Javascript or XSS will see this question and have no idea how to answer it at all, because your question is about Java. It cannot be answered with Javascript code

Comment: Thanks. Will remove these tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already parsing your HTML using JSoup, your next step is to traverse each element to check if they contain Javascript. Something like this code will check each element:

```
boolean validateHtml(String html) {
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  for(Element e : doc.getAllElements()) {
      if(detectJavascript(e)) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}

private boolean detectJavascript(Element e) {
  if(/* Check if element contains javascript */) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then, there are several checks you should perform inside `detectJavacript` function:

- Of course, reject `script` elements: `e.normalName​() == "script"`
- Reject elements with a value in any `on*` attribute (`onload`, `onclick`, etc). You have the complete list [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) but it's probably just enough to get all attributes with `e.attributes​()` and reject if any of them starts with `"on"`.
- Every attribute that accepts a URL (`href`, `src`, etc.) can contain a `"javascript:"` value that executes JavaScript. You should check all those too. For a complete (?) list of these attributes, check [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725156/complete-list-of-html-tag-attributes-which-have-a-url-value).

Finally, I advise not to store the original html into the database, even if it passes your validation. Instead convert the document parsed by JSoup again to html. This way you make sure you have a well-formed document free of any "dangerous" elements.

Comment: Also check answer and comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725156/complete-list-of-html-tag-attributes-which-have-a-url-value